# $f = u + iv$ is holomorphic in $G$ and $au+ibv$ is constant in $G$. Show that $f$ itself is constant in $G$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f = u + iv$ is holomorphic in the region $G\in \mathbb{C}$ and that for pair of complex numbers $a$ and $b$, $au+ibv$ is constant in $G$. Show that $f$ itself is constant in $G$.

**My attempt**: We supposed $a=a_{R}+ia_{I}$ and $b=b_{R}+ib_{I}$, so, from the Cauchy-Riemann equations and 
$$au+ibv=a_{R}u-b_{I}v+i(b_{R}v+a_{I}u)=\mbox{constant.}$$ 
we have
$$
a_{R}u_{x}=-b_{I}u_{y} \quad \mbox{ y } \quad b_{R}v_{y}=-a_{I}v_{x}.
$$
I don't know how to continue with the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $au+ibv$ is constant in $G$, $e^{au+ibv}=c$ in $G$. So $|e^{au}|=|c|$. Thus $u$ is constant in $G$. Since $f=u+iv$ is analytic in $G$, by Cauchy-Riemann equation, $v$ is constant in $G$. Thus $f$ is constant in $G$.